# How to add my module Javascript to *all* pages in Prestashop?

Tags: javascript, module, hook, prestashop

I would like to add a Javascript function to all pages within the store that installs my module.

I read up on [hooks](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Hooks+in+PrestaShop+1.5), and it seems that there's no single "display" hook that I can count on being called for every single page in the store - different pages have different hooks. E.g. I need to use the `displayHeader` hook for "Home page and general site pages" but this doesn't work for product pages.

Is there a way to do this with a single hook, not a list of hooks each for a specific page category?

Note that I don't want to use a theme for this, because my module is meant to be an add-on to the store, not an overarching design template.

**Edit:**

I was wrong saying that `displayHeader` hook doesn't work for product pages. Indeed, as the answer says, that's the one that I need to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you still can use this call
`$this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'your.js');`
 in module `hookDisplayHeader()` method, it will register your js file in js files list that will appear in e.g. `header.tpl` loop by `$js_files`

P.S.

also do not forget about mobile with somethign like:

`public function hookDisplayMobileHeader()
    {
        return $this->hookHeader();
    }`

so module should be registered in 2 hooks **Header** and **mobileHeader** to appear on all devices.

Comment: Yes, it seems displayHeader (and displayMobileHeader for mobile) is the hook I need after all. I'm correcting my question to indicate that. Thanks!